Docker npm install fails and log file does not exists
My dockerfile runs npm install, which fails, it tells me to check a specific log file, but this file does not exists:
=> ERROR [app  9/10] RUN npm config set cafile zscaler.cer     && npm install                                                                                                                             73.1s
------
 > [app  9/10] RUN npm config set cafile zscaler.cer     && npm install:
73.02 npm error Exit handler never called!
73.02 npm error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
73.02 npm error     <https://github.com/npm/cli/issues>
73.02
73.04
73.04 npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-07-03T07_16_45_863Z-debug-0.log
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm config set cafile zscaler.cer     && npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
me@vm:/app$ sudo tail /root/.npm/_logs/2024-07-03T07_16_45_863Z-debug-0.log
tail: cannot open '/root/.npm/_logs/2024-07-03T07_16_45_863Z-debug-0.log' for reading: No such file or directory

I'm a docker noob, and I have no idea how to resolve this without the log file, any idea why it isn't created? docker compose is launched as sudo, so I do not think it is a permission issue, but I might be wrong.

The issue was caused by the version of npm, simply upgrading npm first in the Dockerfile resolved it.

The new Node version 22.5 released 2 days ago is causing this issue, along with its new npm version. Take a look at this: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/7657
For me just downgrading to 22.4 solved the issue.
